# How to add glossary

Tags: glossaries

I'm trying to add a glossary at the end of my thesis following the guide here:

[shareLatex](https://it.sharelatex.com/learn/Glossaries)

So I've used:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, openright]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew,utf8,latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries 
\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
        name=latex,
        description={blablabla}
}
\newacronym{gcd}{FIRST}{blablabla}
begin{document}

....

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary[title= Acronyms and Glossary of Terms]

end{document}
```

without results.
Moreover I'd like to have "Acronyms and Glossary of Terms as a numbered line in table of contents but if I add the option `[toc]` to

```
\usepackage[acronym][toc]{glossaries}
```

I obtain an error "`missing \begin{document}`".

Comment: You need to use `\gls{latex}` inside your document.

Comment: ... and use `\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}` instead of `\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}`. It works for me with `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: I solved using glossaries-extra package. thanks to all!

Comment: Don't pass multiple options to `inputenc`. What could be the point? It tells it the input encoding of your document. Pick whatever that is.

Comment: You are missing a backslash in the line `begin{document}`. You need `\begin{document}`. Similarly in the line `end{document}`.